# Can you use jquery ui tab where some tabs are ajax driven and some static?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I see there [is full ajax mode](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode) but I wanted to see if there is a hybrid mode where some tabs are ajax driven and some static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Each link is independent of the other...  The [AJAX example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) on the demo page has both a static tab and ajax loaded tab.

**Example**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Static</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">AJAX</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```